# Excel / Power Query / Flow Automation Issue

Tags: excel, powerquery, power-automate

I have a Flow in Power Automate that saves the .csv files from an email i receive each day into a folder. I then created an excel document that contains a power query to collate all of the data in the .csv files and transform it into the correct layout required.  The intention was that any member if the team could open the Excel file, refresh that query and export the data into the final destination to publish to the business.

However, it only refreshes for me as the power query is pointing towards my C: drive and I cannot get it to change to a Sharepoint destination.

Is there a better way to handle this process so that any member of the team can refresh it or the refresh can be scheduled on my machine?

I have looked at trying Office Scripts and Power BI but have never used either of them before and have not been able to find a solution that works.

I don't have an Enterprise license for O365 so I know some of the options are not available.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you "cannot get it to change to a Sharepoint destination"? Why can't you change it?

Comment: Make the Flow in Power Automate save to a network shared location. Go into powerquery in home...advanced editor... and change the location reference of the source files

Comment: @Rory When I tried to change the source of the folder that the CSV files are saved into the error message said that it needed to be a static location so I couldn't use the web address for the SharePoint folder.

Comment: @horseyride Thanks, I'll give that a try and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: You should be able to refresh from Sharepoint - what exactly did you try?

Comment: @Rory I went into the power query to data source settings. Selected the data source and Change Source. I then pasted the SharePoint link into the folder path and it gave me a warning that said "The folder path must be a valid absolute file path." I am doing this in the desktop version of Excel if that makes a difference.

Comment: Where did you get the sharepoint path from?

Comment: Also are you using `Sharepoint.Files` or `Folder.Files`? I'm not sure if the latter will work.

Comment: I used the copy link address for the sharepoint folder through the web browser

Comment: I'm using Folder.Files